# How would a python program check its own md5sum?

Tags: python, security, md5, md5sum

I was playing a game about a year ago. Wanting to speed it up a bit, I edited the main .py file and added psyco to the very beginning. The game ran faster and better, but it would not let me send my scores. I went into the file and it was checking its own md5sum. The part that confused me is that they had its md5 in the file. My question is, how do I get the md5 of a file with the sum of the file including the md5 I don't have yet. Seems a catch 22 to me, but they did it.

Hope I explained that well enough. 
Example:

File: Example.example

```
check md5 of Example.example
If md5 I just obtained == "###################################"
allow send score.
```

Comment: Are you sure it was checking the md5 of itself and not a different file? Post some actual code.

Comment: As far as I know, you'd have to generate 'random' MD5 hashes, and see if putting them in that place works. You can get the computer to try that, but it's still likely to be slow.

Comment: Are you sure the high-score server wasn't validating the md5sum? That would make more sense.

Comment: @Falmarri You could be right. As I said, I was playing the game a year ago and actually can not remember the name now. I wanted to find the actual code, but can't. I just thought of it again today.

Comment: @nakedfanatic You are right, that would make more sense. I am pretty sure that the md5 was embedded in the file, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't (easily) embed an MD5 of a program inside the program that it is computing the MD5, because when you change the MD5 of that you are embedding, the program's MD5 changes. Loop for a while and eventually you may reach a stable point. Then again, you may not. "a while" typically means 2^128 steps, so that's going to be a very long while --- like after the sun becomes a red giant.

So there's a trick. When the program computes its own MD5, it specifically recognizes where the embedded MD5 is located and uses a set value, like all NULLs.

To make it harder for hackers, don't use all NULLs --- use a SALT value. Obfuscate that value in your binary. Now it will be harder for people to edit the embedded MD5 and "fix" it after they have edited your program.

Comment: You would still need to have that SALT somewhere in the program so this is not much more secure than just NULLs

Comment: That sounds extremely logical. That would seem to be the way they probably did it. Your reason why it can't easily be done is the reason why I thought it sounded like a catch 22. Your solution is likely what they did. Now, if only I could find the code, I could verify it.

Answer (score 1):

What is usually done in these cases is that when calculating the MD5, the actual number is replaced with some place holder, for instance spaces or zero padding.

This is widely used in cryptography mechanisms like IPSEC.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to do, you would need to brute force it. Are you sure it's not a 
red herring and the real verification is done elsewhere?

Doesn't seem like vert good security anyway, what's to stop you modifying the algorithm like this (using your pseudo code)

```
check md5 of Example.example
If md5 I just obtained != "###################################"
allow send score.
```

Comment: If the code in question is in Python, it's likely to be pretty easy to bypass any security.

Comment: I agree that that would be an easy bypass, but I wasn't really worried about breaking it.  I was just curious how they did such a thing

Comment: You can only brute force it if you have 2^128 cycles available---and even then, there may not be a monostable solution.

Comment: @vy32, That's why I think it's some sort of fake checksum, if it is indeed contained within the same file

Comment: No, it's not. See my answer. You calculate the checksum of the file without counting the embedded MD5.

Comment: @vy32, I count that as a fake md5sum. I fail to see what possible use it could have for any security whatsoever